# what is the difference between multitier web application and multilayer web application?

Tags: asp.net, architecture

what is the difference between multitier web application and multilayer web application?

Comment: As I would understand the terms, absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Layers Refer to specific layers of abstraction with in an application (software) where as tiers Refer to the physical residence of those layers (hardware)

App.Layer == "Software"-----logical
App.Tier == "Hardware"------physical

Layers:
1) presentation layer
2) business layer
3) data access layer
4) data layer
5) external system access layer

Tiers:
1) Presentation tier (webserver)
2) Data tier (database server)

Answer (score 8):

As per my knowledge Tier is usually used to refer to the physical boundaries invloved in the architecture like web server, application server, database server where as
layer is used for logical boundaries like business layer, data access layer ui layer etc.

Answer (score 2):

To build on @Cybernate's answer:

If you have your solution split into UI, Business Logic, and Data Access then each of those is considered as separate layers.

If your data access was deployed on a separate machine and exposed via a web service, then that would be a multi-tiered design.

Answer (score 1):

Multilayer Application  means the logical separation of functionality into assemblies, for example, Data Layer, Presentation Layer, Business Layer etc. All the assemblies may also be deployed in the same physical machine.

Multitier Application is all about the physical deployment.