# when should i use multi-tier web application instead of single tier web application?

Tags: asp.net, architecture

**original question**

when should i use multi-tier web application instead of single tier web application?

**update to my question**

i accepted the following definition to differentiale **"Tier"** and **"Layer"**

**Layers** Refer to specific layers of abstraction with in an application (software) where as **tiers** Refer to the physical residence of those layers (hardware)

App.Layer == "Software"-----logical
App.Tier == "Hardware"------physical

**Layers:**

1) presentation layer

2) business layer

3) data access layer

4) data layer

5) external system access layer

**Tiers:**

1) Presentation tier (webserver)

2) Data tier (database server)

Comment: What do you think of as the "tiers" you're asking about? Definitions vary.  It helps if you provide examples of exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: It depends on the kind of web application you want to build. Do you want build an application that displays the current date? Well, whis could be considered single tier. Do you have content, maybe even users, who might want to login? You'll need at least a database for that - so yes most web applications today can be considered multi-tier, for good reasons.

Comment: This should be added to original question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788419/what-is-the-difference-between-multitier-web-application-and-multilayer-web-appli instead of seperate question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by asking, will the application hold data? If it does, is the data going to be read by multiple users concurrently? How often? Based on the answer to these questions (and many other) you might want to decide whether a database is the way to go.

As far as layers (UI, Data Access, Business Logic, etc) is concerned, it trully depends on a project by project basis. Are you developing a web app for proof of concept? Are you expecting it to maintain it? Do you trust all the developers in your team? But my rule of thumb is to alway use layers unless i'm throwing something together really quick to either prove something or know it will never be maintained and I need to do it fast.

If you decide to use a framework such as MVC, MVP, MVVM, etc then by default you're dividing your app into layers.

Keep in mind that these divisions help you isolate certain aspects of your app, which in turn allow you to easily work with TDD, separation of concerns, maintainabilty, etc.

In conclusion, you have to look at your requirements, goals, team members, and short and long term objectives and decide. There is no white or black answer here

Answer (score 1):

> when should i use multi-tier web application  (Tier == "Hardware"------physical)

Scalability.